# simd_float4x4, SCNMatrix columns not documented

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

`simd structures` and `SCNMatrix4` are not well documented about their columns. Which information can we get from these columns and which order?

I know we can get *position*, *rotation*, *orientation* and *scale* but which column is associated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "transformation matrix" in 3D graphics doesn't store translation, rotation, scale, and perspective per column (or row). Instead these are all stored mixed so that multiplying a 4-element vector with the transformation matrix will "apply" the transformation (that is, the result of the multiplication is the transformed vector) and so that multiplying two transformation matrices produce a new transformation matrix that combines the two.

Because of this it's not very meaningful to describe the columns, rows, or even most cells in the matrix (the diagonal is used for scaling but those same cells are also used for some rotation values).

You can read more about [transformation matrices on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) and [the Wikipedia page for "affine" transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Image_transformation) has some good illustrations of 2D transforms.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would like to get the top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right corner of an `ARImageAnchor` with the correct orientation etc. So if I understood, we should multiply the current world position vector to the anchor transformation to get the anchor position?